# How to pass a JSON data set as a string in a YAML file?

Tags: json, go, yaml

how can i have a key in YAML format which accepts a json data as a string? I tried to put the json data in quotes but it reads as a list of map.

```
test1: '[{'a':'abd','asxs': 'csd','sx':'sft'}]'
test2: default
```

I want yaml to read 'test1' as string rather than a list of dicts/maps. how do i get it?

I get below error:

> Failed while parsing request input: field "Request" field "string" 
>   can only parse list of bytes or characters, invalid element: 
>   map["a":"abd" "asxs":"csd" "sx":"sft"]

Answer (score 0):

Define `test1`  as a `string` instead of `[]map[string]string`. you can use [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) for parsing and loading your data into your `struct`'s fields. hope I understood your question correctly, if not please leave a comment. here's a complete example (make sure to define your vars with capital letter in the beginning e.g. `Test1`)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {
    var data = `
   test1: "[{ 'a': 'abd', 'ases': 'cad', 'sx': 'sft' }]"
   test2: default
   `

    type T struct {
        Test1 string
        Test2 string
    }
    t := T{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    println("test1 value: ", t.Test1)
}
```